# Upgrade Failure in FreePBX Installation

Tags: php, mysql, asterisk, pbx

I'm building FreePBX 2.11.0.25 from source over Asterisk asterisk-11.9.0 (also built from source) on a Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit server installed on a VMWare VM. During installation I had an error that Asterisk version does not match with currently supported versions. I commented that check, to run the code ahead.
After commenting the check, on running `sudo ./install_amp` initial installation goes smoothly. Then it fails while installing the first update. Output:

```
-> Running PHP script /home/xeno/freePBX/freepbx/upgrades/1.10.007beta1/upgradecallgroups.php
Upgrading Call Groups..0 to check...
OK

DB Error: no such table
```

Now, the printed `OK` is the last statement in the PHP file. I tried putting some `out()` statements in the parent script (`libfreepbx.install.php`) to see how far the script goes to determine the exact location of error. It *seems* that the `upgradecallgroups.php` never returns; the error is in this file not in the parent script.

It doesn't look like a compatibility error so I'm sure commenting the version check should not be relevant here.

I am not very fluent in PHP (can read code easily, though) and totally at a loss about this error. Being a beginner, I followed steps from this link for FreePBX installation: http://highsecurity.blogspot.in/2012/12/quick-and-dirty-asterisk-11-and-freepbx.html

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Database named as `asterisk` was needed along with `asteriskcdrdb` but wasn't mentioned in the tutorial.

Creating the database and all tables in it fixed the issue.

Cause: Some SQL scripts in the updates enforce usage of `asterisk` database, even if you override the database in initial settings. To resolve previous errors (which, BTW, also arose because the tutorial failed to mention `asterisk` database), I had also updated the scripts in initial installation to use `asteriskcdrdb` for ALL tables, but not in the scripts provided with updates. Turns out that it is far easier if you use the default (and proper) `asterisk` database instead of overriding all of the SQL scripts. The error was tricky as MySQL specified non-existing tables when the tables existed in a different database.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you get a VMware image (a lot of them can be found on the internet) with freepbx or use PIAF.

You also can try upgrade via web->modules.

Comment: Well, if I wanted only a working copy of FreePBX then I would already have gone for such options. I am installing from source as a hobby and a learning experience.